# php compare 2 array and get what is missing in the last one

Tags: php, php-7

I have two .ini files (key=value)  `config1.ini` and `config2.ini`
containing :

```
KEY_1="value one"
KEY_2="value two"
....
```

config1.ini is complete and bigger
I want to compare config1.ini and  config2.ini and find all the missing keys in config2.ini

thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$config1 = parse_ini_file("config1.ini");
$config2 = parse_ini_file("config2.ini");

$result = array_diff_assoc($config1, $config2);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: it does not work , it returns keys from config1 that are already in config2
array_diff_key  maybe ? it seems that it works

thank you